# GET url varible in Slim v3.2 PHP Stripe checkout

Tags: php, rest, stripe-payments, slim

I cannot get a URL varible in my stripe checkout PHP slim app.

I need to be able to get a price varible from the URL to echo out into the session for the price of stripe payment.
 However it is just not working, I can use $_GET['price']; to echo out before it becomes a SLIM APP however when it becomes a SLIM APP it just wont work...

```
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use Stripe\Stripe;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(realpath('../../'));
$dotenv->load();
Stripe::setApiKey(getenv('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));


$db = new SQLite3('./store.db');
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sessions(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, stripe_id TEXT, status TEXT)");
// createSession
function createSession($sessionId) {
  global $db;
  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO sessions(stripe_id, status) VALUES (:id, 'pending')");
  $stmt->bindValue(':id', $sessionId, SQLITE3_TEXT);
  return $stmt->execute();
}
// markSessionPaid
function markSessionPaid($sessionId) {
  global $db;
  $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE sessions SET status='paid' WHERE :id = stripe_id");
  $stmt->bindValue(':id', $sessionId, SQLITE3_TEXT);
  return $stmt->execute();
}
// getSessionStatus
function getSessionStatus($sessionId) {
  global $db;
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT status FROM sessions WHERE :id = stripe_id");
  $stmt->bindValue(':id', $sessionId, SQLITE3_TEXT);
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  return $result->fetchArray()[0];
}

$app = new Slim\App;

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
  $response->getBody()->write(file_get_contents("../../client/index.html"));
  return $response;
});
$app->get('/success', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
  $response->getBody()->write(file_get_contents("../../client/success.html"));
  return $response;
});
$app->get('/cancel', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
  $response->getBody()->write(file_get_contents("../../client/cancel.html"));
  return $response;
});

function middleware1() {  
    
  $price = $app->request()->get('price');
    
};

$app->post('/create-session', 'middleware1', function(Request $request, Response $response) use ($app)  {
  
  try {
    // One time payments
    $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
      'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
      'line_items' => [[
        'name' => 'Order',
        'description' => 'ORDER ID: 123456789A',
        'images' => ['testimage'],
        'amount' => $price,
        'currency' => 'aud',
        'quantity' => 1,
      ]],
      'success_url' => 'http://localhost:4242/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost:4242/cancel',
    ]);
    // Subscription recurring payments
    // $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    //   // 'customer' => 'cus_123',
    //   'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    //   'subscription_data' => [
    //     'items' => [[
    //       'plan' => 'starter',
    //       'quantity' => 1,
    //     ]],
    //   ],
    //   'success_url' => 'http://localhost:4242/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    //   'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost:4242/cancel',
    // ]);
    createSession($session->id);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    return $response->withJson($e->getJsonBody(), 400);
  }
  return $response->withJson($session);
});

$app->post('/webhook', function(Request $request, Response $response) use ($app)  {

  // You can find your endpoint's secret in your webhook settings
  $endpoint_secret = getenv('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET');
  $payload = $request->getBody();
  $sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
  $event = null;

  try {
    $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
      $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
    );
  } catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
  } catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
    // Invalid signature
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
  }

  // Handle the checkout.session.completed event
  if ($event->type == 'checkout.session.completed') {
    $session = $event->data->object;

    // Fulfill the purchase...
    handle_checkout_session($session);
  }

  return $response->withJson(['message' => 'success']);
});

$app->get('/session-status', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
  $status = getSessionStatus($request->getQueryParam('session_id'));
  return $response->withJson($status);
});

function handle_checkout_session($session) {
  // Call out to inventory management system
  // Ding in Slack
  // send an email
  markSessionPaid($session->id);
}

$app->run();
```

I've tried everything

```
$app->request()->get('price');
```

And more!
The URL looks like this [www.example.com/server/php/?price=5770&orderid=y2INOqCUrEzrua1XwBMg](http://www.example.com/server/php/?price=5770&orderid=y2INOqCUrEzrua1XwBMg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should say what Slim version you are using.

Comment: I am using Slim version 3.2

Comment: Are you sure? The code looks like Slim 2 and not Slim 3.

Comment: @odan composer says "3.2"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use $_GET in Slim since it wont work. One way to do it is since the parameters are passed in query I think you mean it like this checkout/?price=200. If so, then you can access it using this:

```
$queryParams = $app->request()->getQueryParams();
$price = $queryParams["price"];
```

This would probably work